# Input value is showing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

> I want to pass the input value to java script, which is coming from session. It is not happening. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function applicantLogin() {

                var userType = $('#userType').val();
                if (userType === 'admin') {
                    window.location.href = "a.jsp";
                }else if (userType === 'monitoringManger') {
                    window.location.href = "b.jsp";
                }else if (userType === 'ma') {
                    window.location.href = "c.jsp";
                }else if (userType === 'superAdmin') {
                    window.location.href = "d.jsp"; 
                }else if (userType === 'admin1') {
                    window.location.href = "e.jsp";
                }else if (userType === 'la') {
                    window.location.href = "f.jsp";
                }else if (userType === 'ia') {
                    window.location.href = "g.jsp";
                }else if (userType === 'da') {
                    window.location.href = "h.jsp";
                }
            }
        </script>


    <body onload="applicantLogin()">
        <input type="hidden" id="userType" value="<%=session.getAttribute("userType").toString()%>"/>
        <h1>Redirecting ...</h1>
    </body>
```

session value is coming properly in input field . but not in JS.

Comment: You are aware that you're also using `jQuery` too... Which will require you to link to the jQuery library...

Comment: because java script is loading before the page is rendered. so you will get undefined.

Comment: at the end add `else {console.log(userType);}`

Comment: also change the code to use `$(document).ready(function(){` rather than `body onload`

Comment: Ohh. Thanks a lot all. Its working now.. :)

Comment: This is rather nonsense to begin with. Rather than sending a value from the server to the client, only to have the client request a different URL based on that immediately, you should use a server-side redirect in the first place.

Comment: I want to set a value to localstorage. So, I am passing this to JS and then redirecting. Otherwise, I can use XML.

Comment: You can still do a server-side redirect with that - just include (as a one-off / variable-controlled possibility) the code which adds the value to localstorage into the page you're redirecting to, so it can run at page load. That would be my idea anyway, so save an extra page refresh